# How to upload image to s3 from react js using api-gateway and lambda ( contains Python)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My goal is to upload image from reactJS web-app to s3 via api-gateway using lambda with written in python.

React code to upload image via API gateway:

[image]

profile.image_upload just does ajax post.

My first question is FormData a right way to send a image?

I configured API-gateway (IMAGE_API above) to handle requests from uploadImage function. When I print event['body'] in lambda, I get something like below. I am not sure how to process this before I can upload to s3

------WebKitFormBoundary0baBvYH7cO2cFBaY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="e0fd34cb-e7a1-4fd9-8f44-9fe26b06d9e8.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg....

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. A POST request is used to send data to the server, for example, customer information, file upload, etc. using HTML forms.

Comment: Unless of course changing the image / replacing the image etc. then you could always use PUT which should be used to replace all current representations of the target resource with the uploaded content.

Comment: Another option is to use API Gateway to S3 proxy integration. Then, you can validate the request inside of API Gateway and POST the content directly to S3. Not sure if that works for your use case though.